# Convert array element to a string and print first character?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to create an array of strings from user input and print the first letter of each element. I'm aware that I need to convert the array to a string somehow, but unsure how to accomplish this. I was unsuccessful with `Arrays.toString`

Following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many names would you like to enter in this array?: ");
        int numName = inp.nextInt();
        String nameArray[] = new String[numName];
        System.out.println("Enter the names: ");

    for(int i = 0; i <= nameArray.length; i++){
          nameArray[i] = inp.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(nameArray.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over every `String` in the `Array` and then print the first `char`. You can do this using `charAt()` and a loop.

```
for(String str : nameArray) {
   System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
}
```

Or you can use [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-):

```
Arrays.stream(nameArray).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.charAt(0)));
```

---

Also just a few problems with your code:

- You are going to enter into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) problem, because `nextInt()` does not consume the newline. Add a blank `nextLine()` call after `nextInt()`
- You are looping until `<= array.length` which will cause an `indexOutOfBounds` error. You need to only loop until less than `array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Just do another iteration over the "nameArray", and get the first character of each array element, and print it.

For example, you can use for-each:

```
for(String name : nameArray) {
  System.out.println(name.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.stream(nameArray).map(s -> s.charAt(0)).forEach(System.out::println);
```